# Azure Terraform for private DNS and vnet links

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create code to make creating azure private DNS zones and virtual network links. I am attempting to try to create a 2 variables, 1 with a list of private DNS zones and the other a list of our virtual network resource IDs. I can successfully run the code but my issue is that if I go to add any virtual networks, existing network peers want to be destroyed and recreated. while these will recreate fine, I am trying to avoid them being destroyed as it may cause issues with service. I am fairly new to terraform so any pointers would be helpful. I think my issue is within the count statement but unsure what I could do to fix it.

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}

provider "azurerm" { 
  version   = ">= 2.0"
features {}
}

resource "random_id" "random" {
  count = length(var.private_zones) * length (var.linked_virtual_networks)
  byte_length = 2

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "privatezones" {
  name     = "it-eastus-prod-privatedns"
  location = "eastus"
  tags     = var.tags
}


resource azurerm_private_dns_zone private_dns {
  count                = length(var.private_zones)
  name                 = var.private_zones[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.privatezones.name
  tags                 = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  count                 = length(var.private_zones) * length (var.linked_virtual_networks)
  name                  = "vnet-${random_id.random.*.dec[count.index]}"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.privatezones.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns[floor(count.index/length (var.linked_virtual_networks))].name
  virtual_network_id    = var.linked_virtual_networks[count.index % length (var.linked_virtual_networks)]
  tags                  = var.tags
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable private_zones {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "List of private dns zones to be created"
    default = [
            "privatelink.database.windows.net",
            "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net",
            #"privatelink.eastus.azmk8s.io",
            #  "privatelink.westus.azmk8s.io",
            #  "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net",
            #  "privatelink.table.core.windows.net",
            #  "privatelink.queue.core.windows.net",
            #  "privatelink.file.core.windows.net",
            #  "privatelink.web.core.windows.net"
            ]
 }

 variable linked_virtual_networks {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "List of linked virtual networks"
    default = [
               "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx",
                "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx",
            ]
 }


 variable "tags" {
  description = "tags"
  default     = {
           "applicationname" = "DNS"
           "creationdate"    = "7/27/2020"
           "creator"         = "name"
           "environment"     = "Production"
           "owner"           = "Net"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you referring to changing the virtual_network_id on the azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link resource? According to the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.html#virtual_network_id) a change will force a new resource.

Comment: I am looking to be able to add/remove either whole private dns zones or more likely, individual VNETs. it's likely VNET Ids would change or be deleted regularly but that will change my count values and cause every single vnet link to be removed and recreated, while it will work, it will cause brief outages while everything gets relinked.

Comment: I am starting to look at for_each. I was able to modify the code a bit to use maps and private DNS zones work, I am not sure if I can do some kind of nested for_each, IE how do I tell "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" to create a link for every single zone I have and every virtual network?